# Can I search all the text files in a tree (but not the binaries) for a certain string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find, grep

My best shot so far is (for looking for strings in a directory containing a large C program)

```
find ~/example_directory -type f \( -name "*.mk" -or -name "*.[sch]" \) -print0 | xargs -0 -e grep "example_string"
```

Which works pretty well, but it relies on all the interesting things being in .mk makefiles, .c or .h source files, and .s assembler files.

I was thinking of adding in things like 'all files called Makefile' or 'all *.py python scripts', but it occurs that it would be way easier if there were some way to tell find only to find the text files.

If you just run grep on all files, it takes ages, and you get lots of uninteresting hits on object files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grep -rI <path> <pattern>
```

The '-r' switch makes grep recurse, and '-I' makes it ignore binary files.

There are additional switches to exclude certain files and directories (I frequently do this to exclude svn metadata, for example)

Answer (score 11):

GNU grep supports the `-I` option, which makes it treat binary files (as determined by looking at the first few bytes) as if they don't match, so they are essentially skipped.

Comment: Thx a ton, I was searching exactly for this and got kinda confused by the guys on SU who said everything is a binary file?! http://superuser.com/questions/195880/list-find-all-regular-files-in-all-subdirectories-excluding-binary-files

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)?

From the top 10 reasons to use ack:

> ack ignores most of the crap you do not want to search
>
> - ...
> - **binary files**,  core dumps, etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -I` to ignore binary files. Using [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/) instead of xargs will allow you to break up the work into multiple processes, exploiting some parallelism for speedup.

There is an example of how to perform a parallel grep available in the documentation:
http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/man.html#example__parallel_grep

```
find -type f | parallel -k -j150% -n 1000 -m grep -I "example_string"
```